# What OpenCL video cards (or FPGAs) features are needed for high speed multiplication?

Tags: opengl, mathematics, opentk, encryption

I'm benchmarking some cryptographic related software and am looking for video cards that are better at parallel multiplication vs parallel addition.

- Is there any prior work that would graph video card performance against math operations (calculating large digits like 256^2048, calculating the modulus etc.)
- What GPU features should I look for?

Answer (score 1):

You only really have two options when it comes to high performance graphics cards - AMD or NVIDIA.

The simplest answer is to get one of each, and profile your algorithm on both to see which is best in your specific case.

However, my guess based on having seen a few articles like http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/12/07/monster_password_cracking_rig/ is that you probably want an AMD card.